# Same object with the same weight but different behaviour

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

My problem right here is that in the image shown bellow, i have 2 objects with the same weight but one is affected 100% and the other not (Idk if i explained myself good)
[image]

You can see that the bottle is being dragged away more than the container in the belt (having both the same weight). This has happened me before; the thing is that aparently it happens when there are 2 separated objects in a same mesh.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: are you sure that the part that doesn't follow properly is not affected by another bone? Maybe share your file?